# Un-Nesting Tables in HTML

Tags: html, database, parsing, dom, html-parsing

There seem to be a lot of resources around the web about how to nest tables in HTML.  This process does exactly what it sounds like: it puts an HTML table inside an HTML table.  As an example, consider the following table:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>First cell in first table. The cell to the right has the second table in it.</td>
<td>

    <table>
    <tr><td>nested table</td></tr>
    <tr><td>nested table</td></tr>
    </table>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

To my knowledge scraping HTML data in this format and placing it in any conventional database application is very difficult (is this misguided?).  Since there are so many cases in which HTML is pulled from the web and stored in a database it confuses me to see nested tables used so frequently.  Since I can't change this, I would like to find a way to 'un-nest' HTML tables.  That is, to take all the information within the sub-table and rearrange it so that it fits within new or existing fields of the main table (thereby leaving a single table).

So far the only solutions I have found involve learning how to use HTML parsers, which to me are far more complicated than HTML itself.  Has anyone created a tool specifically for the purpose of 'un-nesting' HTML tables upon import to a database?

Comment: `"this format is impossible to use in conjunction with any conventional database application that I am aware of"` - How so?  Outputting data to the page is generally done in any kind of iterative manner, regardless of the markup which surrounds those iterations.  `"So far the only solutions I have found involve learning how to use HTML parsers"` - Oh, you're talking about *scraping* data from HTML.  That's not really explicitly clear in the question.  In that case, you're looking for a DOM parser.  Whatever language you're using likely has at least one.

Comment: @David Good point, I've updated the question to clarify that.